# How to avoid messing formating up?

Tags: html, css

I made a field with rectangles divs. When I put some content into rectangle div formating is messing up. How to fix it? [Here is a link](http://jsfiddle.net/cadmy/qh3sdobk/)

```
<div class = 'line' id = 'line1'>
  <div class ='cell top_cell left_cell' id = 'l1c1'> <font size = "6">&bull;</font></div>
  <div class ='cell top_cell' id = 'l1c2'></div>
  <div class ='cell top_cell' id = 'l1c3'></div>
  <div class ='cell top_cell' id = 'l1c4'></div>
  <div class ='cell top_cell right_cell' id = 'l1c5'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.cell {
    background:#F593D1;
    Width:50px;
    Height:50px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **`overflow:hidden;`**  to  `.top_cell`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qh3sdobk/1/)**

```
.top_cell {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or **`vertical-align:top;`**  to  `.cell`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qh3sdobk/3/)**

```
.cell {
    background:#F593D1;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `vertical-align` property into `.cell` ruleset, setting its property to any value other than `baseline`. For example:

```
.cell {
    vertical-align: top;
    background:#F593D1;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vdz2sa1q/).